# selecting a column from pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, python-3.5

I have the below pivot table which I created from a dataframe using the following code:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='count', index=['days'],columns['movements'], aggfunc=np.sum)

movements 0    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
days
0         2777 51  2                    
1         6279 200 7   3                
2         5609 110 32  4                
3         4109 118 101 8   3            
4         3034 129 109 6   2   2        
5         2288 131 131 9   2   1        
6         1918 139 109 13  1   1        
7         1442 109 153 13  10  1        
8         1085 76  111 13  7           1
9         845  81  86  8   8            
10        646  70  83  1   2   1   1
```

As you can see from pivot table that it has 8 columns from 0-7 and now I want to plot some specific columns instead of all. I could not manage to select columns. Lets say I want to plot column 0 and column 2 against index. what should I use for y to select column 0 and column 2?

```
plt.plot(x=table.index, y=??)
```

I tried with `y = table.value['0', '2']` and `y=table['0','2']` but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select ndarray for `y` if you need those two column values in a single plot you can use:

```
plt.plot(table['0'])
plt.plot(table['2'])
```

If column names are intergers then:

```
plt.plot(table[0])
plt.plot(table[2])
```

Comment: Thanks. The column names are integers. When I do plt.plot(x=table.index, y=table[0]), I do not get any error but somehow plotting function does something wrong. It just shows an empty plot with x and y range of -0.5 - 0.5. However, doing print(table[0]) does show right data. Somehow, plt.plot(table[0]) and later plt.plot(table[2]) seems to work.